# How to convert JSOM response to simple object

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

I'm using some javascript code to retrieve the workflow definitions on my site:

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = _context.get_web();
var serviceManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(context, web);
var deploymentService = serviceManager.getWorkflowDeploymentService();
var definitions = deploymentService.enumerateDefinitions();

context.load(definitions);

return context.executeQuery()
         .then(function(){
             console.log(definitions);
             var enumDefs = definitions.getEnumerator();

             while(enumDefs.moveNext()){
             ....
         });
```

BTW I've wrapped **executeQueryAsync** with jQuery Deferred so my JSOM code can resemble my REST code. Here is a [John Liu's blog](http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/convert-sharepoint-jsoms-executequeryasync-to-promise-in-the-prototype) on how to do that.

This is working and I can clunkily iterate my way through the list. But I really, really dislike using the SP complex types and all their methods.

In the browser I see that a nice simple json array is being send back as the response. Is there anyway I can just get that?

Is there some way to easily change all the information that comes back into a json object?

Comment: Why is it clunky? How are you using this query?

Comment: How is it not clunky? :) First I have to getEnumerator() then uses a while(enum.moveNext()) then for every property or piece of information I want I have hope they included a getter method for it and also know what it is called and of course for each different call it will be different types with different property names. Finally once I leave the complete/success handler the data is gone. With a json object I can just return the object from my asych call and iterate over all of the values. Unless there is something like that and I just don't know what it is?

Comment: Just store it in a json object or array on load or onclick (however you are triggering the fetch), then you can rummage through it after page load.

Comment: Yes that is my question. How do I do that? With my debug tools I see definitions item, but it is a complex object with methods and things that I don't need. If I try JSON.stringify(definitions) I get an Converting circular structure to JSON error. I think what I want is in enumDefs.get_current().$5_0.$H_0, but that doesn't seem like a stable way to work. Is there a simple and understandable way to convert it?

Comment: something like `var wfarray []; var enumDefs = definitions.getEnumerator();

             while(enumDefs.moveNext()){
             var currentwf = enumDefs.get_current();
             wfarray.push(currentwf);
}
//do something with wfarray;`

Comment: But later when us wfarray each element will still be some crazy thing that I can't inspect in the debugger or get the values from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a next code to get simple objects

```
return context.executeQuery()
     .then(function(){
         return definitions.get_data().map(function(item) {
           return item.get_objectData().get_properties();
         });
     });
```